# Use tensor flow predictions and convert that to image

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to run some inferences on a trained model.

Now, I get the result back from my tensorflow,

```
def load_graph():
    ''' This method loads the graph '''
    print 'load graphs'
    pb_graphs = ['/Users/pm/Downloads/frozen_graph.pb']
    graphs = []
    for each in pb_graphs:
        with tf.gfile.GFile(each, "rb") as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
            tf.import_graph_def(
                graph_def,
                input_map=None,
                return_elements=None,
                name=""
            )
        graphs.append(graph)
    oos_graph = graphs[0]
    print 'graph loaded'
    return oos_graph


def run_inference(graph):
    sess = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False))
    # (1892, 11776),(1892, 12288),(1892, 12800),(1892, 13312),(1892, 9728)]:
    for each in [(1892, 11264)]:
        y,x = each
        print y,x
        y1 = y + 1024
        x1 = x + 1024

        pano_images = pano_img[y:y+1024,x:x+1024]

        x_batch = pano_images.astype('float32')
        pred_boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name("decoder/cat:0")
        pred_confs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("decoder/shape:0")
        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x_in:0")
        feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch}
        t1 = datetime.now()
        np_pred_confs, np_pred_boxes = sess.run([pred_confs, pred_boxes], feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)      
        t2 = datetime.now()
        delta = t2 - t1
        print 'time taken in seconds == ', delta.total_seconds()
        print 'np_pred_boxes ==', np_pred_boxes.shape
        print 'np_pred_confs ==', np_pred_confs.shape
        print 'np_pred_boxes ==', type(np_pred_boxes.shape)
        print 'np_pred_confs ==', type(np_pred_confs.shape)     
        with sess.as_default():
            img = Image.fromarray(pred_boxes.eval())
            img.save('/Users/pm/Downloads/tf_image.png')
```

I want take the pred_boxes and generate a image and see what tensorflow has predicted.

Using the below code to convert the tensorflow prediction to image ie; convert it to numpy array and generate a image.

but it does not work. Read that I can use a eval() function to convert the tensor to numpy array.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x_in' with dtype float and shape [1024,1024,3]
     [[Node: x_in = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1024,1024,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. It seems that there is missing bits (`test_in` placeholder, `x_in` node, to cite a few)

Comment: Updatd the code with all the information.

Comment: It seems that the variable you're trying to feed your model with, `x_batch`, is either the wrong shape, or the wrong type. Are you sure the image you're using has 3 channels ?